# MERGE: when not matched insert using select statement

Tags: oracle

I am looking for the right syntax to insert from a select statement in merge, Here is what i did for the moment, and i have an ORA-00926:

```
MERGE INTO table A
USING table B ON (...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (column 1, column 2, ...)
SELECT column 1, column 2, ...
FROM table C
INNER JOIN other tables ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [merge_insert_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#i2090698) shows that keyword `values` and brackets are mandatory. I would try to join tables `b` and `c` as source table and compose `on` part accordingly.

Comment: can you give an example for that please, I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Sure: [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08ee60d3679cff81a48844e435b2755c). Please read comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table A
USING table B ON (...)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (c1, c2) VALUES (
(SELECT c1 FROM table C WHERE ...),
(SELECT c2 FROM table C WHERE ...)
)
```

Comment: I think that would be too long since I have so many arguments to take in consideration

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to write these statements is to put the data you're trying to merge into the `USING` clause. And you don't give us your `ON` clause, so I can't really tell how that works.

```
MERGE INTO table_a A
USING ( SELECT B.id, C.col_1, C.col_2
          FROM table_c B
          LEFT JOIN table_c C on C.id = B.id ) D
   ON ( A.id = D.id )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( col_3, col_4 )
      VALUES ( D.col_1, D.col_2 )
```